# Making table columns in email signature stack vertically on mobile

Tags: html, css

My email signature looks basically like this on desktop:

[image]

On mobile it gets too wide and the phone number and "Schedule Meeting" text breaks/wraps; like this:

[image]

Instead, I would like it to look something more like this when the screen width gets too low; so the logo is above the text:

[image]

**How can I mark up / style the table so that the whole first column (holding the image) breaks to its own row instead of words wrapping within a column?**

Here is my current code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="90"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/pz0BRLt/logo.png" alt="" width="75" /></td>
<td width="300">
<p>Fname Lname<br />Founder + CEO ▸&nbsp;<a href="https:/example.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">OurBrand</a><br /><a href="mailto:fname@example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">fname@example.com</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="tel:15555555555" target="_blank" rel="noopener">1.555.555.5555</a><br /><img width="16px" />&nbsp;<a target="_blank" rel="noopener">Linkedin</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img width="16px" />&nbsp;<a target="_blank" rel="noopener">Schedule meeting</a></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<p><strong>Word | Word | Word | Word</strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please also note: I am using gmail, which means I can only copy and paste the *rendered content* into the signature field—meaning I can't use media queries or a separate `<style>` tag, as that won't carry over. It all needs to be inline.